# how to map two matrix values in github workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm getting two outputs from previous job. in my next job i need to pass these output but each output should take one value only.

```
jobs:

  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest    

 `steps:
      - name: Set color
        env:
         test: "[{'ip':'192.168.11.1'},{'ip':'192.168.11.2'}]"
        id: set-color-var
        run: echo "vapps=${{ env.test }}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
    
      - name: set product
        env:
         setup: "[product1,product2]"
        id: set-product
        run: echo "product=${{ env.setup }}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"  
         
    outputs:
      apps: ${{steps.set-color-var.outputs.vapps}} 
      product: ${{ steps.set-product.outputs.product }} 
               
  get-color:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job1
    strategy:
     matrix:
      host: ${{fromJSON(needs.job1.outputs.apps)}}
      bundle: ${{needs.job1.outputs.product}}

    steps:
      - name: install ${{matrix.bundle}} on ${{matrix.host.ip}}
        run: echo "installation will start"`
```

i want matrix to take one host and one product and it should not repeat any host or product. in above code each host is taking both the product.

Also i have tried with 'include' in matrix but in that case unable to print the value.

```
`get-color:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job1
    strategy:
     matrix:
      host: ${{fromJSON(needs.job1.outputs.apps)}}
      include: 
      - bundle: ${{needs.job1.outputs.product}}
    steps:
      - name: install ${{matrix.include.bundle}} on ${{matrix.host.ip}}
        run: echo "installation will start"`
```